# How to analyze every file in every folder in a specific path

Tags: python

I'm having troubles with the next problem:

I'm creating a program that has to analyze every file (these are photographs, I'm extracting metadata of them) in every subfolder of a specific path that I indicate to the program.

My code is getting that path from a different file (config.ini) that I indicate manually, but will be introduced by someone in the GUI (it's not created yet so I have to introduce the path manually); and it would be like that for example:
C:/folderA/folderB;
Inside of this folder, there will be subfolders, like this:
C:/folderA/folderB/one, two, three (three or more different subfolders inside folderB);
and I would like my code to analyze every one of these three different folders to extract all the metadata that is inside of every file in these subfolders.

As code, I actually have this, but only analyzes the files in the specific folder I indicated (I didn't write it, I'm quite new with Python; this code was given to me by a partner to work on it):

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(imgdir):
        for f in filenames:
            if '.jpg' in f:
               -code that analyse photographs-
```

What should I try to solve this problem? Sorry if this question is too rookie or is already answered, I tried to search something specific like this question but didn't find anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi diazze, what exactly is your issue? Since `os.walk` enters all folders and subfolders recursively, I think it does what you want (judging from what you've shown us).

Comment: Hi jfaccioni. It is this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\program1\\tests\\folderA\\folderB/001_photo.jpg'. The thing is, inside of folderB there are 3 folders (C,D and E), and it's not entering to analyse; but I don't understand what is it doing, because 001_photo is the first photograph of folder C... So I guess it should be 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\program1\\tests\\folderA\\folderB/ FOLDERC / 001_photo.jpg'

Comment: I can't be sure because I haven't seen the code, but I believe in the "code that analyse photographs" part you're eventually calling a function that loads the image, something similar to `load_image(f)`. This will make Python look for the file f *in whichever folder Python is currently executing*, not in the folder you actually want deep down the folder tree. Use something like `path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)` and then `load_image(path)`. Another potential issue, looking at the message error, is a mix of forward and back slashes. But like I said I'd need to see the full code to be sure.

Comment: @jfaccioni problem solved. I wasn't calling correctly the variables, now I fixed it and it's working. What I actually need is to save the actual path of the file in a variable, in order to compare the actual name of the photo with the actual name of the folder. I'm using the commando df['name of the photo']str.contains('variable with folder's actual name') (i.e. photo1_folderA.jpg contains 'folderA' in its name? True)